# Python - How to avoid refer multiple names to one dict

Tags: python, iterable, refer

I am struggling with python dictionary. I have two dics named `defaultSettings` and `personalSettings`. I want to make function sets `personalSettings`'s values to `defaultSettings`'s values. But I don't want to all changes be applied to `defaulSettings`.

I tried this code:

```
defaultSettings = {'s1': 1, 's2':2, 's3':3}

personalSettings = {'s1': 3, 's2':2, 's3':1}

print(defaultSettings)
print(personalSettings)
print('-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*')

personalSettings = defaultSettings

print(defaultSettings)
print(personalSettings)
print('-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*')

personalSettings['s1'] = 5

print(defaultSettings)
print(personalSettings)
```

And my output is:

```
{'s1': 1, 's2': 2, 's3': 3}
{'s1': 3, 's2': 2, 's3': 1}
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
{'s1': 1, 's2': 2, 's3': 3}
{'s1': 1, 's2': 2, 's3': 3}
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
{'s1': 5, 's2': 2, 's3': 3}
{'s1': 5, 's2': 2, 's3': 3}
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

If I change a value of `personalSettings` after `personalSettings = defaultSettings`, `defaultSettings`'s value changes too. I know this;

[image]

But I don't know how avoid this or other way.

Comment: You are currently making `personalSettings` another name for `defaultSettings`. Do you want to make `personalSettings` refer to a copy of `defaultSettings`, or do you want to update `personalSettings` in place, replacing the current contents with the contents of `defaultSettings`? (If you don't understand the distinction, see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.)

Comment: @chepner is correct, you should call `.copy()` if you want an actual `copy` instead of a `reference`.

Comment: You can also use `personalSettings.update(defaultSettings)` to merge them.

Comment: @chepner I want to update  `personalSettings` in place, replacing the current contents with the contents of `defaultSettings`. I understand the distinction if I don't, probably I were thinking "Where is the error?! It should be work!"

Comment: @Barmar No, I don't want to merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

```
>>> defaults = {'foo': 'bar', 'bee': 'blah'}
>>> actual = dict(defaults)
>>> actual['foo'] = 'BAZ'
>>> defaults
{'foo': 'bar', 'bee': 'blah'}
>>> actual
{'foo': 'BAZ', 'bee': 'blah'}
```

The trick is `actual = dict(defaults)`. This way `actual` can be changed without affecting defaults.

If your dicts have sub-objects, consider `deepcopy` or `json.dumps/loads` to make a deep copy:

```
>>> myDict = {'s1':1,  's2':{'b1':2, 'b2':3}}
>>>
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>>
>>> myDict2 = deepcopy(myDict)
>>>
>>> myDict2['s2']['b1'] = 99
>>>
>>> myDict
{'s1': 1, 's2': {'b1': 2, 'b2': 3}}
>>> myDict2
{'s1': 1, 's2': {'b1': 99, 'b2': 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `defaultSettings.copy()` or `dict(defaultSettings)` to create a copy of the dict